# Solving a set of equations with radicals in $\mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I want to solve set of equations $\begin{cases}\sqrt{y^2-8x+9}-\sqrt[3]{xy+12-6x}\le 1\\\sqrt{2\left(x-y\right)^2+10x-6y+12}-\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{x+2}\end{cases}$

Here is what I've done :

$\left(2\right)\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{2\left(x-y\right)^2+10x-6y+12}-\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x+2}=0$

$\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{2\left(x-y\right)^2+10x-6y+12}-2\sqrt{y}-\left(\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{y}\right)=0$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{2\left(x-y\right)^2+10x-6y+12-4y}{\sqrt{2\left(x-y\right)^2+10x-6y+12}+2\sqrt{y}}-\frac{x+2-y}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{y}}=0$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{2\left(x-y+3\right)\left(x-y+2\right)}{\sqrt{2\left(x-y\right)^2+10x-6y+12}+2\sqrt{y}}-\frac{x-y+2}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{y}}=0$

$\Leftrightarrow \left(x-y+2\right)\left(\frac{2\left(x-y+3\right)}{\sqrt{2\left(x-y\right)^2+10x-6y+12}+2\sqrt{y}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{y}}\right)=0$

$\Rightarrow x=y-2\left(1\right)\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{y^2-8\left(y-2\right)+9}-\sqrt[3]{\left(y-2\right)y+12-6\left(y-2\right)}\le 1$

$\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{y^2-8y+25}-\sqrt[3]{y^2-8y+24}\le 1$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{y^2-8y+25-9}{\sqrt{y^2-8y+25}+3}-\frac{y^2-8y+24-8}{\sqrt[3]{\left(y^2-8y+24\right)^2}+4+2\sqrt[3]{y^2-8y+24}}\le 0$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{\left(y-4\right)^2}{\sqrt{y^2-8y+25}+3}-\frac{\left(y-4\right)^2}{\sqrt[3]{\left(y^2-8y+24\right)^2}+4+2\sqrt[3]{y^2-8y+24}}\le 0$

$\Leftrightarrow \left(y-4\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2-8y+25}+3}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\left(y^2-8y+24\right)^2}+4+2\sqrt[3]{y^2-8y+24}}\right)\le 0$

$\Rightarrow y=4\Rightarrow x=2$

Check for me, please.

Comment: It is correct down to the point where you conclude that $y=x+2$ but you lost me at the second step after that where the $\le0$ first appears. I believe your final result because I used desmos to draw the graphs where it is plain that as the constant term under the first radical of equation (2) approaches $12$ from the left, the graph of the second equation approaches the graph $y=x+2$ for $x\ge-2$ which is tangent to the region defined by equation (1) at the point $(2,4)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you have shown is that $(x,y)=(2,4)$ is a solution, and that you have not shown that it is the only solution.

---

First of all, we have to have $$x+2\ge 0\quad\text{and}\quad y\ge 0\tag1$$
Now
$$\sqrt{2\left(x-y\right)^2+10x-6y+12}=\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt y$$
Squaring the both sides,$$2(x-y)^2+10x-6y+12=x+2+y+2\sqrt{y(x+2)}$$
Rearranging$$2\sqrt{y(x+2)}=2x^2-4xy+2y^2+9x-7y+10$$
Squaring the both sides,$$4y(x+2)=(2x^2-4xy+2y^2+9x-7y+10)^2$$
to have$$(x-y+2)^2((2x-2y+5)^2+8y)=0$$
So,$$x-y+2=0\quad\text{or}\quad (2x-2y+5)^2+8y=0$$
From $(1)$, $$y=x+2\quad\text{or}\quad 2x-2y+5=y=0$$
to have$$y=x+2$$

Substituting this into the inequality gives$$\sqrt{(x+2)^2-8x+9}-\sqrt[3]{x(x+2)+12-6x}\le 1$$
Setting $t:=x^2-4x+12$,$$\sqrt{t+1}-t^{1/3}\le 1$$
Rearranging $$\sqrt{t+1}\le 1+t^{1/3}$$
Squaring the both sides$$t+1\le 1+2t^{1/3}+t^{2/3}$$
to have$$t\le 2t^{1/3}+t^{2/3}$$
Dividing the both sides by $t^{1/3}\gt 0$, and rearranging $$t^{2/3}-t^{1/3}-2\le 0$$
To have$$(t^{1/3}-2)(t^{1/3}+1)\le 0$$
Dividing the both sides by $t^{1/3}+1\gt 0$ $$t^{1/3}\le 2$$
to have
$$x^2-4x+12\le 2^3$$
so$$(x-2)^2\le 0$$
giving $$x=2$$
It follows from above that $(x,y)=(2,4)$ is necessary.

Since $(x,y)=(2,4)$ is sufficient, we see that $\color{red}{(x,y)=(2,4)}$ is the only solution.